# How to get TableCell Value from TableRow in Table at FlowDocument in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, flowdocument, tablerow

I want to get all the data from a `TableRow`, when row is clicked in `WPF`.

```
currentRow = tab.RowGroups[0].Rows[r];
currentRow.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(test);

void test(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   try 
   {
      TableRow tr = sender as TableRow;
      // After that what i do to read TableCell Value
   } 

   catch(Exception ex) 
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Please help...

Comment: sorry, it's .net 4.5 version, i'm using 4.0 :( any other solutions

Comment: friend, TableCell Item properties disabled here. how to enable it.

Comment: TableRow tr = sender as TableRow;
  TableCellCollection tc = tr.Cells;

  // I can't access tc.Item, because it show error like this..

Comment: oh my god! I'm live as single in the world, because no one answer my ? :(

Comment: You can access only to TableCells like the above not to Paragraphs or Runs. To access the latter you should assign each name on them before you make new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run())).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late, and you're probably not still here, let alone still on this project, but for those who might view this in the future: To get the data from each cell, after

```
TableRow tr = sender as TableRow;
```

do something like the following:

```
// I imagine you'd want to start a list here
// that will hold the contents of your loops' results.
List<string> resultsList = new List<string>();
foreach(var tableCell in tr.Cells)
{
    // May want to start another list here in case there are multiple blocks.
    List<string> blockContent = new List<string>();
    foreach(var block in tableCell.Blocks)
    {
        // Probably want to start another list here to which to add in the next loop.
        List<string> inlineContent = new List<string>();
        foreach(var inline in block.Inlines)
        {
            // Implement whatever in here depending the type of inline,
            // such as Span, Run, InlineUIContainer, etc.
            // I just assumed it was text.
            inlineContent.Add(new TextRange(inline.ContentStart, inline.ContentEnd).Text);
        }
        blockContent.Add(string.Join("", inlineContent.ToArray()));
    }
    resultsList.Add(string.Join("\n", blockContent.ToArray()));
}
```

It might be a good idea to read up on the FlowDocument hierarchy. A decent place to start is [MSDN's Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @SHINJaeGuk Generically, you're correct. You would have to figure out which kind of `Block` type you want to process. It could be something like `foreach(var block in tableCell.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>())` for instance. If you use `OfType`, make sure you put a `using System.Linq` at the top of your .cs file.